# Printing list backwards

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with this program which is to print out a list forwards and backwards, however When I print out the list backwards the first number in the list is a random massive number rather than the right number. e.g.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
4286398 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

can anyone explain what is wrong with my code please.

Also Can anyone tell me how I could pass the counter from the printList function to a new function called checkList() so that the counter has the same value in checkList() as what it is at the end of printList().

code:

```
void printList(int array1[]){
int counter = 0;
int x;
ifstream theFile("list.txt");

while(theFile >> x){
    array1[x] = x;
    cout << array1[x] << " ";
    counter = counter + 1;
}
cout << endl << counter << endl;;

int n = counter;

for(int i = n -1; i >= 0; i--){
    cout << array1[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: it looks like a garbage number

Comment: What are the contents of list.txt?

Comment: it also looks like you're printing your counter.  why isn't that part of the output you've posted

Comment: Looks like some output has certainly been cut off

Comment: Ah, the counter was a test, not actually intending to print that.  also the contents are just the numbers 0-8 and 0 again for now.

Comment: @Thomas then you should remove that print statement, and then re-compile and run your code, and post the output you get.

Comment: @Thomas if you have 0-8 and then 0 again, the problem is the statement `array1[x] = x`. Your counter will be at 9, but you have never written `array[9]` and so you get uninitialized garbage.

Comment: @NikBougalis that is a more articulate explanation than any of the correct answers posted here

Comment: Change your test case: Instead of having the array-index like sequence, change the contents of "list.txt" to more random looking numbers (e.g. 3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 7, 4, 5 ) and run your program. That way, you will be able to see the issue far more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem because of the line `array1[x]=x;`. Your code would actually work if the numbers in your file were 0..9, but the final number is another 0, so you don't set array1[9] to anything.

You should have some variable for indexing the array, something like:

```
int counter = 0;
while(theFile >> x){
    array1[counter] = x;
    cout << array1[counter] << " ";
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: If he's outputting what he just read, he should also have `cout << array1[counter]`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, missed that line :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's the culprit:

```
array1[x] = x;
```

If your array input values are `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0`, then at the last iteration of your loop you're doing `array1[0] = 0`. That overwrites the first item in your array, while incrementing the counter. Then, when you reverse it `array[9]` contains garbage value because you never set it.

Answer (score 4):

you are doing

```
array1[0] = 0;
array1[1] = 1;
array1[2] = 2;
array1[3] = 3;
array1[4] = 4;
array1[5] = 5;
array1[6] = 6;
array1[7] = 7;
array1[8] = 8;
array1[0] = 0; // here
```

array1[9] is uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

You have some serious issues in the code:

```
ifstream theFile("list.txt");
while(theFile >> x){
   array1[x] = x;//^^this is evil
   cout << array1[x] << " ";
   counter = counter + 1;
}
cout << endl << counter << endl;;
                             //^^extra colon, though not wrong here but not good practice
```

You read from file and fill the array, in your special case, you have:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```

You have 10 elements, but your `array1` will end up with `9` since the last read was `0` and `array1[0]` was written as `0` again. So when you output your `array1`, you will never get `10` numbers since your array actually stores 9 numbers. that's why you saw garbage value if you try to access `array1[9]`, which value has not been filled, some garbage raw memory value.

Instead, you can try to do the following:

```
int counter = 0;
int x;
ifstream theFile("list.txt");

while(theFile >> x){
    array1[counter] = x;
    cout << array1[counter] << " ";
    counter = counter + 1;
}
cout << endl << counter << endl;;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are counting wrong upwards and eventually hit uninitialized memory AFTER your array. You should pass the length of your array as a parameter to your function.
As arrays decay to pointers you won't be able to recover its length.

```
void printList(int array1[], into size){ }
```

Then thou don't need to figure out its length so complicated.

Comment: Actually, he should just take a `std::vector<int>&`, and use `push_back`.  Then he can output the reversed array using `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Comment: True, but if OP wants to use arrays, fine with me :-P

Comment: Given the way the question was stated, I suspect that it is homework, and he has to use C style arrays, even if it is "wrong" in this context.  I have the impression that there are a lot of bad teachers out there.

Comment: Agreed! Maybe they are back from the old days, when PDP-11 was high-end ;)